# Unable to turn off laptop when wifi is on

Tags: 16.04, wireless, laptop

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP ProBook 4540s. Legacy (bios) is used because of grub problems during installation with uefi.
During installation with legacy have raised no errors. The wifi button has still orange color - in on and off state. But it should be blue while wifi is on.

When i try to turn off laptop using GUI or terminal (`sudo poweroff`, `sudo shutdown -h now`) while wifi is on, it restarts the laptop. It is possible to shutdown the laptop only when wifi is off (using hw button).

Thank you for solutions.

Comment: Have you tried systemctl poweroff ?

Comment: and sudo init 0 and so on - it only restarts the computer

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`.

Answer (score 0):

This link [is the best I found](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Laptop-restarts-immediately-after-told-to-shutdown/td-p/2945749):

Re: Laptop restarts immediately after told to shutdown
Options
‎04-18-2016 01:01 PM
Hello. I am so sad for those who suffer this problem. I have had spent so many hours on the web to find a solution. The same happened to me when I upgraded my Probook 4540s to windows 10. First I realised bluetooth is no more operative and dissappeared from device manager. Then , my computer restarted every time I shut it down, wanting to bluetooth to work again, I guess. I read thousand of threads on the web in various websites. I applied every single solution offer, hoping it might turn to normal again. Never worked though. Then I gave it up to force to fix it. That is when the magic happened. Out of boredom I replaced my wi-fi card with the one installed on my spare laptop, accepting all the restarting thing, at least with an operative bluetooth. When my HP loaded up, bluetooth was working just fine, along my HP shuts down properly as I have shut it down thousands of time since then, out of joy.
My advice to fix this issue would be to replace any device which does not properly working, especcialy if you have done an OS upgrade. It would be the only solution for this kind of issues.

Good luck to all.

Comment: In work we use ubuntu, on my desktop i use ubuntu an everything is ok. So i wanted to have ubuntu in my ntb too. It seems like there are no right drivers for ubuntu because i'm on win 10 now and everything seems to work ok.
Thank you for your answer. I just asked and checked if this is a common problem with simple sollution.